# Citing court cases in APA 7 with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, legal-style, apa7

I'm having trouble citing a U.S. District Court case using the `apa7` class with Biber.

According to [this reference](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/apa_legal%20references%20.html), the format should be as follows (using the information I need in my citation):

> Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc. 872 F. Supp. 2d. 974 (2012). https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20120601k39

In this case, the volume is 872, the name of the book is F. Supp. 2d. (including the periods), and the page number is 974.

I've defined my reference as follows:

```
@book{initial_suit,
    author = "{\relax Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc.}",
    volume = {872},
    book = "{\relax F. Supp. 2d.}",
    page = {974},
    date = {2012-05-31}
}
```

And I've cited it in my document as follows:

```
\parencite{initial_suit}
```

I get the correct format for the in-text citation, but the bibliography at the end of my document is completely incorrect. I see the following:

[image: actual result]

How should I format my Biber citation to correctly display the contents?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@book{initial_suit,
 author = "{\relax Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc.}",
 volume = {872},
 book = "{\relax F. Supp. 2d.}",
 page = {974},
 date = {2012-05-31}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}    

\title{Minimum Working Example}
\shorttitle{Lorem Ipsum}    

\author{nhubbard}
\authorsaffiliations{TeX.SX}    

\leftheader{TeX.SX}    

\abstract{
  \textbf{TODO: Write this abstract \textit{after} writing the rest of the proposal.}
}    

\keywords{example}    

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    This is a citation. \parencite{initial_suit}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` comes with an extensive example `.bib` file which includes many - if not all - examples from the APA manual. Especially for more complex and less common entry types I highly recommend you have a look at that file if you don't know how to format your `.bib` entries.

For court decisions have a look at [the entry `11.4:3` (ll. 2488-2497 in `biblatex-apa-test-references.bib`)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/12fbacae95fc6b7a67505711138363bec5361f37/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L2488-L2497) and the following entries.

Here you might end up with something like

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\title{Minimum Working Example}
\shorttitle{MWE}
\author{nhubbard}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@jurisdiction{initial_suit,
  title         = {Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc.},
  citation      = {872 F. Supp. 2d. 974},
  url           = {https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20120601k39},
  date          = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  This is a citation. \parencite{initial_suit}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc., 872 F. Supp. 2d. 974 (2012). https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20120601k39]

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I didn't know that bib file reference existed until now, I'll keep a bookmark to it for future reference.